# How to pass parameter to jQuery document.ready() function (jstl, MVC, java)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring-mvc, jstl

in my .jsp file I have code like this (to the point)

```
<td width="200px">
  <input type="text" id="${general.pk.code }_${MTPL[4].pk.run}"
  name="${general.pk.code }_${MTPL[4].pk.run}"
  value="${MTPL[4].value}" onChange="gg('${MTPL[4].jsCode }','${MTPL[4].pk.code }',this,'${MTPL[4].operator }','${MTPL[4].param1 }','${MTPL[4].param2 }','${MTPL[4].param3 }','${MTPL[4].param4 }','${MTPL[4].param5 }','${MTPL[4].pk.run }','${MTPL[4].param6 }','${MTPL[4].param7 }')"
  style="text-align: right;">
</td>

<c:forEach items="${valueRun }" var="generalR">
  <td width="200px">
    <input type="text" id="${general.pk.code }_${generalR}"
    name="${general.pk.code }_${generalR}"
    value="" onChange="gg('${MTPL[4].jsCode }','${MTPL[4].pk.code }',this,'${MTPL[4].operator }','${MTPL[4].param1 }','${MTPL[4].param2 }','${MTPL[4].param3 }','${MTPL[4].param4 }','${MTPL[4].param5 }','${MTPL[4].pk.run }','${MTPL[4].param6 }','${MTPL[4].param7 }')"
    style="text-align: right;">
  </td>
</c:forEach>
```

when page finish load, the value be like this (inspect element)

> input type="text" id="MTPL_4" name="MTPL_4" value="1100" onchange="gg('COPAS','MTPL_4',this,'','this','','4','','','4','','MTPL')"
>   style="text-align: right;">

I want to get parameter on function gg() at javascript document ready. How to do that.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var a = $("#MTPL_4").val(param1); //didnt get param1 value
  });
</script>
```

I try `.val()` but its only get value (1100). How get value inside onchange function `gg();`
(try to get "COPAS",'MTPL_4', etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery *attr* method for this and then get substring out of it like below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var len = $("#MTPL_4").attr("onchange").length;
    alert($("#MTPL_4").attr("onchange").substring(3, len-1));
})
```

Further if you want to split the string and get individual parameter which is separated by "," you can use *split* method.

Comment: how can I get value based on parameter name ? like param1, jscode, etc. because I'm gonna use for calculate in another function like param2+param3.

Comment: So, you know the sequence of parameter, right? Like jscode, code, operator, param1, ..., para5, run, param6 and param7. So now when you will split the value based on '.' like str.split(',') you will get an array of all the parameter value. Now you can associate it with some key and value and make a new array and pass it on to another method. Does it make sense?